# Is it possible to checkout files from subversion without those .svn folders?

Tags: asp.net, svn

Is it possible to checkout files from subversion without those .svn folders? (for publishing .NET apps to release server).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

yes. Just export.

```
svn export REV URL PATH
```

the contents of URL will be placed in PATH. (Path and rev is optional.)

Obviously, you should not use this command for starting to work on the files.

Comment: @Hugo The -r option is required for specifying the revision number.

Comment: So if your repo is at https://foobar.com/folder you just type `svn export https://foobar.com/folder folder`

Answer (score 5):

**TortoiseSVN** Version of Hugo's answer:

Use the **Repo-Browser** to browse to the folder you want to export, Right-Click - > **Export**, follow the dialog

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use the export option.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout by definition requires the subdirectories to manage the file's states. Without them you would not be able to check in if you make changes. You can export but that is not the same as checkout. You can also change the name from .svn to _svn if that is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you export, can't commit. Try use a checout and next rename .svn or _svn to another names.

Note _svn and .svn is reserved folders for tortoise svn.

Comment: Sounds to me like he wants to get the files onto the release server where, I suspect, he won't make changes that he ever wants to commit.